# Setting cookie for the server's own domain

Tags: java, servlets, cookies, cors

I work both on client and server. When developing, my client runs on `http://localhost:3000/` while my server runs on `https://local.somedomain.com`. The server sends a cookie like

```
set-cookie: a=aB5Th....;Path=/;Expires=Sun, 02-Aug-2020 11:26:36 GMT;Max-Age=5184000
```

This cookie is needed for a download link looking like

```
https://local.somedomain.com/api/v2/ExportSomething.xlsx
```

however, it isn't there. As the server didn't specify a domain, it might make sense. OTOH, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20090012/581205), "You can't modify the cookies of one domain using a servlet or JavaScript hosted on another domain, for security reasons", and I *don't want* to set any cookie for any domain except the one the server runs on, so I'm asking *why to specify anything when there's no choice*?

Filtering "Has blocked cookies" in Chromium devtools shows nothing, which I'd interpret as "everything is fine, cookies came through". *Am I wrong?*

The strange thing is that it used to work one or two weeks ago, at least in Chromium (and I'm very sure about that as I worked a few hours on the export). Now it works in none of the four browsers I have tried. *Any explanation?*

Assuming it's necessary to specify the domain when setting the cookie, is [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300670/how-to-get-the-domain-name-from-the-request-in-a-java-servlet#comment60979917_7300693) correct?

#### Boring details

- every request sets the cookies in the same way
- no requests beside the above download link use cookies
- CORS is obviously needed and works and every request gets handled the same way
- there are no other servers involved

#### Update

I've just tried `cookie.setDomain("local.somedomain.com")` and also this with a leading dot and it didn't help.

I also tried leaving out the `Max-Age` (which also removes `Expires` which was otherwise added automatically) and it didn't help either (someone claimed that only session cookies work on localhost).

Comment: afaik if you don't need to set a domain, the cookie will be for local.somedomain.com. Is it correct that you see the cookie in the server response of the Chrome debugger, but *not* in the Application -> Cookies -> https://local.somedomain.com? Do you have extensions possibly blocking something?

Comment: @Simon Correct, I can see the cookie as above in the Network tab (or using curl), but it's missing in Application / Cookies. I tried four browsers, two of them freshly installed, so there were no extensions.

Comment: Could you quickly check if anything changes when you start Chrome with `--enable-file-cookies` ?

Comment: The fact that all 4 browsers reject the cookie indicates at something more general. What are you using as local certificate for HTTPS? Are you possibly using a non-trusted CA?

Comment: @Simon I'm using a valid Let's Encrypt certificate, obtained in the same way as we do in production. I though, using `http://localhost:3000` for the client could be the culprit, but `http://192.168.100.7:3000` doesn't work either. I also tried to access the server with plain HTTP as `http://local.somedomain.com:10080` and `http://localhost:10080` and other combinations, none worked.

Comment: right, if the certificate were buggy the browser would complain anyway, that was a wrong path. Is it something like this here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43865038/browser-wont-store-cookie (cross-domain Ajax requests)

Comment: @Simon I'm using fetch with `{mode: 'cors', headers: {authorization: ....}, credentials: 'same-origin'}` and the cookie doesn't get sent with the request... but this doesn't matter as my fetch requests don't need it (they have the `authorization` header), only following the link `<a href=....>` does need it. This may be somewhat related, but I guess, the problem is that the cookies doesn't get stored at all. Damn.... that was it....

Comment: @Simon The cookie wasn't *accepted* because of `credentials: 'same-origin'`, which is [documented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/credentials) as "Send user credentials (cookies, basic http auth, etc..) if the URL is on the same origin as the calling script". I don't care about *sending* the cookie with the request, I only need it to be *received* so it can be sent with a link click request.

Comment: @Simon If you can make any sense of it, feel free to write an answer and I'l accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible reasons for such behavior (that I can think of):

1. The browser settings reject all third-party cookies (if localhost receives a cookie from `local.somedomain.com`, that would be considered third-party)
2. A browser extension is blocking the cookie
3. The `local.somedomain.com` server response does not include the necessary CORS headers to allow `localhost` to receive the cookie. (Access-Control-Allow-Origin must be present and not set to '*', Access-Control-Allow-Credentials must be present and 'true')
4. Google is messing with you

That last point is actually not a joke, and most likely the cause here. Google has been tweaking the "SameSite" rules for cookies in Chromium, documented here: https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site

An a related case on SO: [Confusion regarding SameSite changes with Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60768119/confusion-regarding-samesite-changes-with-chrome)

Comment: FTR: My solution is to add request header `credentials: window.location.hostname.match(/local(?:\.|host)/) ? 'include' : 'same-origin'` to my fetch request, so it's secure unless served locally. It works.... till the next funny change.